# How do I make the Phone Number mandatory on the Contact Us form: Solved

Tags: magento2.3

how do I make the Phone Number mandatory on the Contact Us form in Magento 2.3?

I was expecting it to be an option in the Admin section but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the template file in you app/design.

> Path
>   :app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

add below code on the place of phone number field.

```
<div class="field telephone required">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" aria-required="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - thanks for the prompt response. This line is telling me that it is trying to validate an email address and not a telephone number - data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"

Comment: Yes , you can change that validation type to number